# Angularjs ng-disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angular-validation, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have two inputs for validating email and password. I can see individuals of the following works:

```
myForm.$error.required
```

validating input form with required input value 
and

```
myForm.email.$valid
```

validating my regex email

If i was to print i.e. {{ with the above code}} i can see the boolean result of the validation for both input and its correct. 
However when I use ng-disabled on button with  both expression it doesnt work but if i put ng-disable with only one expression I can see it does work but I am unable to place both expression i.e.

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$error.required && !myForm.email.$valid">Sign in</button>
```

Currently the result becomes true based on the first expression but i thought && meant both condition needs to be met in order to result true ?
Could it be because the ouput is true + false = true ?

Comment: try this `myForm.$error.required || !myForm.email.$valid`

Comment: So, you want the button to be disabled when `myForm` contains some error related to a required field and at the same time the `email` is not valid?

Comment: debug the statement with {{ myForm.$error.required && !myForm.email.$valid }}. decompose to see what is going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`true + false` doesn't mean `true && false`, it means `true || false`,

that's why you don't get the right behavior, so:

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$error.required || !myForm.email.$valid">Sign in</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" if you want to disable the button while the whole form is invalid.

In case you want to disable the button if the email is not provided or email is not valid so you should use || instead of && so the button will be disabled in both cases.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: Not really, it's an alternative to the question desired, but still answers it.